# PHP file_exists() can't check file existence when URL rewrite is enabled?

Tags: php, zend-framework, url-rewriting

in Zend FW:

```
file_exists('xx/xxx/xxxx.jpg');
```

returned 1, but xx/xxx/xxxx.jpg is not file or directory.

it's an error page returned by Zend FW. because it's not a file or valid url

how can I check file existence?

Comment: That function is a native PHP function... Try running it in a PHP script without the Zend Framework to see what happens. Also, that beginning / means it's loaded from the top of the OS filesystem, not from the top of the server URL.

Comment: Note also that file_exists() is cached, so if the file does exist, is tested, then removed, then tested again, the second test will still return true.

Comment: You can clear the cache with clearstatcache():  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php

Comment: file_exists() isn't checking a URL, so your error page has nothing to do with this here.  (Note, it can check a URL in *some* cases, but again, that isn't what you are doing here.)

Comment: @thomas-hunter I edit my question and remove /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) checks whether a file or directory exists. 
Try use [is_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php)

Comment: is_file works, why? there is no such file or directory in my file system, but file_exists return 1 and is_file return 0

Comment: strange, maybe you had a file or directory there before and it has been cached by file_exists

Answer (score 0):

To check for existence over HTTP, you need to check the HTTP response codes. The easiest way to do that IMO is using curl. Try this:

```
$url = 'http://google.com/this_does_not_exist.jpg';
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10);//timeout
$res = curl_exec($ch);
$code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

switch ($code % 100){
    case 2:  echo "exists\n"; break;
    case 3:  echo "too many redirects\n"; break;
    case 4:  echo "does not exist\n"; break;
    case 5:  echo "5xx error - may or may not exist once server fixed\n"; break;
    default:
             echo "Something weird. HTTP response code = $code\n";
}
```